# How to clear display settings cache

Tags: display

How do I clear the "cache" (remembered settings such as whether to mirror or have two separate displays or what my preferred resolution is for a monitor)?

Comment: Why? This seems awfully specific and there might be a better way to accomplish what you're trying to do

Comment: On a Mac mini, the display that I have has crapped out. Weirdly enough, it works at some resolutions and not others. It does work at its native resolution, which wasn't what I had it set at. My friend is letting me borrow a monitor temporarily to control the machine. So I figure if I can wipe out the configuration cache, and plug my monitor back in, I can use it at its native resolution.

Comment: Interesting issue. I'll do some more research, but if nothing else, [SwitchResX](http://www.madrau.com/) might be able to help, as I believe what displays you've connected over time are remembered.

Comment: You can also try [clearing NVRAM.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063)

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting

```
/Users/YourUserName/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.preference.displays.\[long number].plist
```

replacing YourUserName and the long number with what you see on your system.

[Reference](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2385757)